# Prevent headless opening of inappwebview in android flutter url_launcher plugin

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a requirement to open the in app web browser in flutter and for that I used the plugin `url_launcher` (https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). After the integration in iOS it opens up the inapp browser as expected with a closable option. However in Android, it opens up the browser in full screen mode where I cannot able to close the web browser, unless I press the system back button.

Any idea how I can achieve this requirement to have a close button? or do I need to do any setting to enable the soft back/close button for android?

This is the view in iOS with closable options.

[image]

This is the view in Android. Please see the source code below on how I am opening the browser.

[image]

```
launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/"),
              mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LaunchMode.externalApplication parameter.

```
await launchUrl(_url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

Comment: Hi @Luki, I do not want to open the external browser. My requirement is to open the in-app browser with a closable button/option. I worked with Xamarin and it opens the in-app browser with a 'X' on the top right corner in all android devices, but flutter in-app browser does not have that option it seems. I am still not sure whether this is an issue with the plugin or flutter.

Comment: Did you find an answer?